# How to record and play back audio in real time on OS X

Tags: macos, audio, avfoundation

I'm trying to record sound from the microphone and play it back in real time on OS X. Eventually it will be streamed over the network, but for now I'm just trying to achieve local recording/playback.

I'm able to record sound and write to a file, which I could do with both `AVCaptureSession` and `AVAudioRecorder`. However, I'm not sure how to play back the audio as I record it. Using `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` works:

```
self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];

AVCaptureAudioDataOutput *audioDataOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];

self.serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("audioQueue", NULL);
[audioDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:self.serialQueue];

if (audioInput && [self.captureSession canAddInput:audioInput] && [self.captureSession canAddOutput:audioDataOutput]) {
    [self.captureSession addInput:audioInput];
    [self.captureSession addOutput:audioDataOutput];

    [self.captureSession startRunning];

    // Stop after arbitrary time    
    double delayInSeconds = 4.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [self.captureSession stopRunning];
        });

} else {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't add them; error = %@",error);
}
```

...but I'm not sure how to implement the callback:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    ?
}
```

I've tried getting the data out of the `sampleBuffer` and playing it using `AVAudioPlayer` by copying the code from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144877/1176156), but that code crashes on the `appendBytes:length:` method.

```
AudioBufferList audioBufferList;
NSMutableData *data= [NSMutableData data];
CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &audioBufferList, sizeof(audioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);

for( int y=0; y< audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++ ){

    AudioBuffer audioBuffer = audioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
    Float32 *frame = (Float32*)audioBuffer.mData;

    NSLog(@"Length = %i",audioBuffer.mDataByteSize);
    [data appendBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize]; // Crashes here

}

CFRelease(blockBuffer);

NSError *playerError;
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&playerError];
if(player && !playerError) {
    NSLog(@"Player was valid");
    [player play];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error = %@",playerError);
}
```

**Edit** The `CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer` method returns an OSStatus code of -12737, which according to the documentation is `kCMSampleBufferError_ArrayTooSmall`

**Edit2**: Based on [this mailing list response](http://www.lists.apple.com/archives/quicktime-api/2013/Apr/msg00015.html), I passed a `size_t` out parameter as the second parameter to `...GetAudioBufferList...`. This returned 40. Right now I'm just passing in 40 as a hard-coded value, which seems to work (the OSStatus return value is 0, atleast).

Now the player `initWithData:error:` method gives the error:

`Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)"` which I'm looking into.

I've done iOS programming for a long time, but I haven't used AVFoundation, CoreAudio, etc until now. It looks like there are a dozen ways to accomplish the same thing, depending on how low or high level you want to be, so any high level overviews or framework recommendations are appreciated.

## Appendix

### Recording to a file

Recording to a file using `AVCaptureSession`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(captureSessionStartedNotification:) name:AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification object:nil];
    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureDevice *audioCaptureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioCaptureDevice error:&error];

    AVCaptureAudioFileOutput *audioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioFileOutput alloc] init];


    if (audioInput && [self.captureSession canAddInput:audioInput] && [self.captureSession canAddOutput:audioOutput]) {
            NSLog(@"Can add the inputs and outputs");

            [self.captureSession addInput:audioInput];
            [self.captureSession addOutput:audioOutput];

            [self.captureSession startRunning];

            double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [self.captureSession stopRunning];
            });
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Error was = %@",error);
        }
}

- (void)captureSessionStartedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    AVCaptureSession *session = notification.object;
    id audioOutput  = session.outputs[0];
    NSLog(@"Capture session started; notification = %@",notification);
    NSLog(@"Notification audio output = %@",audioOutput);

    [audioOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[[self class] outputURL] outputFileType:AVFileTypeAppleM4A recordingDelegate:self];
}

+ (NSURL *)outputURL
{
    NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"z1.alac"];
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
}
```

Recording to a file using `AVAudioRecorder`:

```
NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    @(kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
                                    AVFormatIDKey,
                                    nil];


    NSError *recorderError;
    self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[[self class] outputURL] settings:recordSettings error:&recorderError];
    self.recorder.delegate = self;
    if (self.recorder && !recorderError) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
        [self.recorder recordForDuration:10];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failure, recorder = %@",self.recorder);
        NSLog(@"Error = %@",recorderError);
    }
```

Comment: Well as this bounty draws to a close, the good news is that I'm 5 Chapters into *Learning Core Audio* and I feel close to a solution using AudioQueues.

Comment: Are you open to using 3rd-party audio libraries? Un4Seen has the BASS audio library that is a fantastically simple wrapper for Core Audio functions. It is capable of doing what you describe (though I'm unsure how close to real time you could get).

Comment: @BigMacAttack I'd like to stick away from 3rd party libraries because I hope to eventually stream to an iOS device. The good news is that I just finished writing the code to answer my question and will post the code after I clean it up.

Comment: Fair enough. And congrats on figuring it out! But I would also like to mention, for others reading this, that BASS is available on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I ended up working at a lower level than `AVFoundation` -- not sure if that was necessary. I read up to Chapter 5 of *Learning Core Audio* and went with an implementation using Audio Queues. This code is translated from being used for recording to a file/playing back a file, so there are surely some unnecessary bits I've accidentally left in. Additionally, I'm not actually re-enqueuing buffers onto the Output Queue (I should be), but just as a proof of concept this works. The only file is listed here, and is also on [Github](https://github.com/MaxGabriel/AudioPlaythrough).

```
//
//  main.m
//  Recorder
//
//  Created by Maximilian Tagher on 8/7/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Tagher. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

#define kNumberRecordBuffers 3

//#define kNumberPlaybackBuffers 3

#define kPlaybackFileLocation CFSTR("/Users/Max/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/Taylor Swift/Red/02 Red.m4a")

#pragma mark - User Data Struct
// listing 4.3

struct MyRecorder;

typedef struct MyPlayer {
    AudioQueueRef playerQueue;
    SInt64 packetPosition;
    UInt32 numPacketsToRead;
    AudioStreamPacketDescription *packetDescs;
    Boolean isDone;
    struct MyRecorder *recorder;
} MyPlayer;

typedef struct MyRecorder {
    AudioQueueRef recordQueue;
    SInt64      recordPacket;
    Boolean     running;
    MyPlayer    *player;
} MyRecorder;

#pragma mark - Utility functions

// Listing 4.2
static void CheckError(OSStatus error, const char *operation) {
    if (error == noErr) return;

    char errorString[20];
    // See if it appears to be a 4-char-code
    *(UInt32 *)(errorString + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
    if (isprint(errorString[1]) && isprint(errorString[2])
        && isprint(errorString[3]) && isprint(errorString[4])) {
        errorString[0] = errorString[5] = '\'';
        errorString[6] = '\0';
    } else {
        // No, format it as an integer
        NSLog(@"Was integer");
        sprintf(errorString, "%d",(int)error);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s (%s)\n",operation,errorString);

    exit(1);
}

OSStatus MyGetDefaultInputDeviceSampleRate(Float64 *outSampleRate)
{
    OSStatus error;
    AudioDeviceID deviceID = 0;

    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress;
    UInt32 propertySize;
    propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice;
    propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    propertyAddress.mElement = 0;
    propertySize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
    error = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject,
                                                &propertyAddress, 0, NULL,
                                                &propertySize,
                                                &deviceID);

    if (error) return error;

    propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate;
    propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    propertyAddress.mElement = 0;

    propertySize = sizeof(Float64);
    error = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(deviceID,
                                                &propertyAddress, 0, NULL,
                                                &propertySize,
                                                outSampleRate);
    return error;
}

// Recorder
static void MyCopyEncoderCookieToFile(AudioQueueRef queue, AudioFileID theFile)
{
    OSStatus error;
    UInt32 propertySize;
    error = AudioQueueGetPropertySize(queue, kAudioConverterCompressionMagicCookie, &propertySize);

    if (error == noErr && propertySize > 0) {
        Byte *magicCookie = (Byte *)malloc(propertySize);
        CheckError(AudioQueueGetProperty(queue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, magicCookie, &propertySize), "Couldn't get audio queue's magic cookie");

        CheckError(AudioFileSetProperty(theFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, propertySize, magicCookie), "Couldn't set audio file's magic cookie");

        free(magicCookie);
    }
}

// Player
static void MyCopyEncoderCookieToQueue(AudioFileID theFile, AudioQueueRef queue)
{
    UInt32 propertySize;
    // Just check for presence of cookie
    OSStatus result = AudioFileGetProperty(theFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &propertySize, NULL);

    if (result == noErr && propertySize != 0) {
        Byte *magicCookie = (UInt8*)malloc(sizeof(UInt8) * propertySize);
        CheckError(AudioFileGetProperty(theFile, kAudioFilePropertyMagicCookieData, &propertySize, magicCookie), "Get cookie from file failed");

        CheckError(AudioQueueSetProperty(queue, kAudioQueueProperty_MagicCookie, magicCookie, propertySize), "Set cookie on file failed");

        free(magicCookie);
    }
}

static int MyComputeRecordBufferSize(const AudioStreamBasicDescription *format, AudioQueueRef queue, float seconds)
{
    int packets, frames, bytes;

    frames = (int)ceil(seconds * format->mSampleRate);

    if (format->mBytesPerFrame > 0) { // Not variable
        bytes = frames * format->mBytesPerFrame;
    } else { // variable bytes per frame
        UInt32 maxPacketSize;
        if (format->mBytesPerPacket > 0) {
            // Constant packet size
            maxPacketSize = format->mBytesPerPacket;
        } else {
            // Get the largest single packet size possible
            UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
            CheckError(AudioQueueGetProperty(queue, kAudioConverterPropertyMaximumOutputPacketSize, &maxPacketSize, &propertySize), "Couldn't get queue's maximum output packet size");
        }

        if (format->mFramesPerPacket > 0) {
            packets = frames / format->mFramesPerPacket;
        } else {
            // Worst case scenario: 1 frame in a packet
            packets = frames;
        }

        // Sanity check

        if (packets == 0) {
            packets = 1;
        }
        bytes = packets * maxPacketSize;

    }

    return bytes;
}

void CalculateBytesForPlaythrough(AudioQueueRef queue,
                                  AudioStreamBasicDescription inDesc,
                                  Float64 inSeconds,
                                  UInt32 *outBufferSize,
                                  UInt32 *outNumPackets)
{
    UInt32 maxPacketSize;
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(maxPacketSize);
    CheckError(AudioQueueGetProperty(queue,
                                    kAudioQueueProperty_MaximumOutputPacketSize,
                                    &maxPacketSize, &propSize), "Couldn't get file's max packet size");

    static const int maxBufferSize = 0x10000;
    static const int minBufferSize = 0x4000;

    if (inDesc.mFramesPerPacket) {
        Float64 numPacketsForTime = inDesc.mSampleRate / inDesc.mFramesPerPacket * inSeconds;
        *outBufferSize = numPacketsForTime * maxPacketSize;
    } else {
        *outBufferSize = maxBufferSize > maxPacketSize ? maxBufferSize : maxPacketSize;
    }

    if (*outBufferSize > maxBufferSize &&
        *outBufferSize > maxPacketSize) {
        *outBufferSize = maxBufferSize;
    } else {
        if (*outBufferSize < minBufferSize) {
            *outBufferSize = minBufferSize;
        }
    }
    *outNumPackets = *outBufferSize / maxPacketSize;
}


#pragma mark - Record callback function

static void MyAQInputCallback(void *inUserData,
                              AudioQueueRef inQueue,
                              AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,
                              const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime,
                              UInt32 inNumPackets,
                              const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDesc)
{
//    NSLog(@"Input callback");
//    NSLog(@"Input thread = %@",[NSThread currentThread]);
    MyRecorder *recorder = (MyRecorder *)inUserData;
    MyPlayer *player = recorder->player;

    if (inNumPackets > 0) {

        // Enqueue on the output Queue!
        AudioQueueBufferRef outputBuffer;
        CheckError(AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(player->playerQueue, inBuffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity, &outputBuffer), "Input callback failed to allocate new output buffer");


        memcpy(outputBuffer->mAudioData, inBuffer->mAudioData, inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize);
        outputBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize;

//        [NSData dataWithBytes:inBuffer->mAudioData length:inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize];

        // Assuming LPCM so no packet descriptions
        CheckError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(player->playerQueue, outputBuffer, 0, NULL), "Enqueing the buffer in input callback failed");
        recorder->recordPacket += inNumPackets;
    }


    if (recorder->running) {
        CheckError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL), "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
    }
}

static void MyAQOutputCallback(void *inUserData, AudioQueueRef inAQ, AudioQueueBufferRef inCompleteAQBuffer)
{
//    NSLog(@"Output thread = %@",[NSThread currentThread]);
//    NSLog(@"Output callback");
    MyPlayer *aqp = (MyPlayer *)inUserData;
    MyRecorder *recorder = aqp->recorder;
    if (aqp->isDone) return;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        MyRecorder recorder = {0};
        MyPlayer player = {0};

        recorder.player = &player;
        player.recorder = &recorder;

        AudioStreamBasicDescription recordFormat;
        memset(&recordFormat, 0, sizeof(recordFormat));

        recordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2; //stereo

        // Begin my changes to make LPCM work
            recordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
            // Haven't checked if each of these flags is necessary, this is just what Chapter 2 used for LPCM.
            recordFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;

        // end my changes

        MyGetDefaultInputDeviceSampleRate(&recordFormat.mSampleRate);


        UInt32 propSize = sizeof(recordFormat);
        CheckError(AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo,
                                          0,
                                          NULL,
                                          &propSize,
                                          &recordFormat), "AudioFormatGetProperty failed");


        AudioQueueRef queue = {0};

        CheckError(AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat, MyAQInputCallback, &recorder, NULL, NULL, 0, &queue), "AudioQueueNewInput failed");

        recorder.recordQueue = queue;

        // Fills in ABSD a little more
        UInt32 size = sizeof(recordFormat);
        CheckError(AudioQueueGetProperty(queue,
                                         kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription,
                                         &recordFormat,
                                         &size), "Couldn't get queue's format");

//        MyCopyEncoderCookieToFile(queue, recorder.recordFile);

        int bufferByteSize = MyComputeRecordBufferSize(&recordFormat,queue,0.5);
        NSLog(@"%d",__LINE__);
        // Create and Enqueue buffers
        int bufferIndex;
        for (bufferIndex = 0;
             bufferIndex < kNumberRecordBuffers;
             ++bufferIndex) {
            AudioQueueBufferRef buffer;
            CheckError(AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(queue,
                                                bufferByteSize,
                                                &buffer), "AudioQueueBufferRef failed");
            CheckError(AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(queue, buffer, 0, NULL), "AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer failed");
        }

        // PLAYBACK SETUP

        AudioQueueRef playbackQueue;
        CheckError(AudioQueueNewOutput(&recordFormat,
                                       MyAQOutputCallback,
                                       &player, NULL, NULL, 0,
                                       &playbackQueue), "AudioOutputNewQueue failed");
        player.playerQueue = playbackQueue;


        UInt32 playBufferByteSize;
        CalculateBytesForPlaythrough(queue, recordFormat, 0.1, &playBufferByteSize, &player.numPacketsToRead);

        bool isFormatVBR = (recordFormat.mBytesPerPacket == 0
                            || recordFormat.mFramesPerPacket == 0);
        if (isFormatVBR) {
            NSLog(@"Not supporting VBR");
            player.packetDescs = (AudioStreamPacketDescription*) malloc(sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription) * player.numPacketsToRead);
        } else {
            player.packetDescs = NULL;
        }

        // END PLAYBACK

        recorder.running = TRUE;
        player.isDone = false;


        CheckError(AudioQueueStart(playbackQueue, NULL), "AudioQueueStart failed");
        CheckError(AudioQueueStart(queue, NULL), "AudioQueueStart failed");


        CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 10, TRUE);

        printf("Playing through, press <return> to stop:\n");
        getchar();

        printf("* done *\n");
        recorder.running = FALSE;
        player.isDone = true;
        CheckError(AudioQueueStop(playbackQueue, false), "Failed to stop playback queue");

        CheckError(AudioQueueStop(queue, TRUE), "AudioQueueStop failed");

        AudioQueueDispose(playbackQueue, FALSE);
        AudioQueueDispose(queue, TRUE);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I try to run your code. But it still echo when i speak. How do you handle for echo cancellation.

Comment: I don't know how to do that in software—I just used headphones